How to Avoid "No module named 'dotenv'" Error After Installing python-dotenv in Anaconda Environment?
I used VS Code and created a conda enviroment. Then I wrote the following code:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    temperature=0.7,
)

response = llm.stream("Write a poem about AI")
# print(response)

for chunk in response:
    print(chunk.content, end="", flush=True)

this is the error i get:
PS C:\Users\langchain_python> py llm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\langchain_python\llm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

I get no module error for dotenv. But I already installed python-dotenv with 'conda install python-dotenv'.I use conda enviroment and when I wrote dot env to terminal this is the output i get(Not sure if its the right way for checking python-dotenv):
dotenv 
Usage: dotenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  This script is used to set, get or unset values from a .env file.

I have deleted dotenv from the base(global env) and created new enviroment again to try. However any of them didn't work. What can I do?
I used ubuntu and my code worked. I wish good luck to everyone.

I don’t know ehere the dotenv command line utility is coming from but it has nothing to do with the Python dotenv module, which is provided by the PyPI package ‘python-dotenv’ (there are multiple packages with “dotenv” in the name, but ‘python-dotenv’ is the one you want).

Yes python dotenv is what I want. I have it. But, I can't import it. What can i do?

add to the top of your code import sys and print(sys.executable). Run your code, waht does it print?

Very good catch! My python exe location is this:
C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
However I want my python exe file to be here:
C:\Users\X.conda\envs\env2\python.exe
Any suggestion? thanks for the comment.

The usage of dotenv is similar to this:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

Therefore your syntax seems to be correct.
To install dotenv with conda use the following command:
conda install python-dotenv

If you want to access the needed variables from your environment do the following:
import os
VARIABLE = os.environ.get("VARIABLE")


When I try to install python-dotenv I get this message from the template:
# All requested packages already installed.
However, when I try to run my code I get this error.
'''
C:\Users\x\Desktop\langchain_python\ py llm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\langchain_python\llm.py", line 1, in 
from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
'''

Did you install the package inside the conda environment? Do you execute your code with the conda environment activated? Can you see the package when executing "conda list"?

Yes, I installed the package inside the conda environment. I executed my code with the conda enviroment activated. I chose the right enviroment's python exe on VS Code. I can see the package when i executed "conda list". This is what i see:
python-dotenv             1.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
and this is the python version in conda list:
python                    3.12.3          h2628c8c_0_cpython    conda-forge
